# Exporting all Charts as PNG

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007

I'm trying to export all charts within my Excel file as a PNG image. The charts are not embedded in the worksheets, but have instead been *moved as a new sheet* upon creation.

Not being familiar with VBA or office macros, I've tried stringing together something based on code examples I found on the web but with no success.

Here's what I've tried, which may work with charts embedded within worksheets but not with standalone charts:

```
Private Sub ExportChartsButton_Click()
    Dim outFldr As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim co As ChartObject

    outFldr = GetFolder(ActiveWorkbook.Path) 
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each co In ws.ChartObjects
            co.Export outFldr & "\" & ws.Name & ".png", "PNG"
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

When the button is clicked, nothing seems to happen.

If I replace the inner loop with `MsgBox co.ChartObjects.Count` I get a `0` popup for each of my non-chart worksheets, so I'm obvious not iterating through the right objects (hence, no charts so nothing happens).

So, how do I iterate through Charts that are not embedded within worksheets?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution. I had to use `ActiveWorkbook.Charts` instead of `.Worksheets`.

```
Private Sub ExportChartsButton_Click()
    Dim outFldr As String
    Dim wc As Chart
    Dim co As ChartObject

    outFldr = GetFolder(ActiveWorkbook.Path)
    If outFldr = "" Then
        MsgBox "Export Cancelled"
    Else
        For Each wc In ActiveWorkbook.Charts
            wc.Export outFldr & "\" & wc.Name & ".png", "PNG"
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

And for the record, `GetFolder()` is defined as:

```
Function GetFolder(strPath As String) As String
    Dim fldr As FileDialog
    Dim sItem As String
    Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With fldr
        .Title = "Select folder to export Charts to"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = strPath
        If .Show = True Then sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
    GetFolder = sItem
    Set fldr = Nothing
End Function
```

Comments/suggestions very welcome.

Comment: Thank, but I believe I can only accept my own answer after 2 days. Which is a good thing since I'm not familiar with vba and would welcome improvements or better solutions.

Comment: Thanks. Nice to know I wasn't way off.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps one of the easiest way to export by far is to save the whole workbook as a webpage. Excel will then automatically convert your charts to PNG's