# Export graphs from Excel

Tags: excel, vba, graph, export

I was wondering how to export graphs from excel instead of using Snipping tool ... I found some code [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8040695/exporting-all-charts-as-png/51031621?noredirect=1#comment89056241_51031621) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11939087/export-chart-as-image-with-click-of-a-button). But I remain stuck with the following error :

```html
"Run-Time error '424'": Object required
```

(same as on link 2) but I can't figure out where does it come from ...

Any thoughts where to start by ?

```html
Sub SaveAllCharts()

Dim SaveToDirectory As String

Dim myChart As Chart

SaveToDirectory = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Images\"

MsgBox ("Saved Directory:" + SaveToDirectory)

For Each myChart In ActiveWorkbok.Charts MsgBox (OK) myChart.Export SaveToDirectory & myChart.Name & ".png", PNG Next

End Sub
```

Comment: You wrote `ActiveWorkbok` instead of `ActiveWorkbook` but I dont think this is your only issue

Comment: `Option Explicit` is your friend here.

Comment: You mean add Option explicit at the beggining of the code ?

Comment: I mean at the top of every module, always.  At least that would point out your typos.

Answer (score 0):

There were a couple of errors in your code `Option Explicit` is a great way to find typos as a couple people said.

Another error was with on your `myChart.Export (SaveToDirectory & myChart.Name & ".png", PNG)` line. You do not need the filterName so `myChart.Export (SaveToDirectory & myChart.Name & ".png")` is perfectly ok for this occasion

Full Code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub SaveAllCharts()

Dim SaveToDirectory As String

Dim myChart As Chart

SaveToDirectory = ActiveWorkbook.Path

MsgBox ("Saved Directory:" + SaveToDirectory)

For Each myChart In ActiveWorkbook.Charts
myChart.Export (SaveToDirectory & myChart.Name & ".png")
Next myChart

End Sub
```

I have tested this code and it works on my pc if you get any issues i will try to help you out

Hopes this helps

Comment: Thanks it works pretty well. My only error - other than Option Explicit and miswriting in Workbook - was to have ', PNG)' at the end ? What is the meaning of that ?